# React EsLint - Component should be written as pure function and after changed it to pure function can't read the property anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this simple class before I change it to pure function as eslint told me to do

```
 class user extends Component {
          render(){
            return(
              <Aux>
        <UserTable title="User" type="user" role={this.props.location.roleAction}/>
              </Aux>
            )
          }
        }
    export default user;
```

and then I got the eslint error said that component should be written as pure function and I try  to change that to pure function like down bellow

```
    const user = () => (
      <Aux>
        <UserTable title="User" type="user" role={this.props.location.roleAction} />
      </Aux>
    );  

export default user;
```

and after change it to arrow function, I can't read the *this.props.location.roleAction* I got an error "cannot read property "location" of undefined " .why is that could happen? any solution to fix the error so I can using the arrow function and able to read the property. it work fine when I use the previous written component.

any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: `this` keyword is only valid for referencing it's own class. And then, see the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pure function ("Stateless Functional Component" or SFC) form, you receive props as a parameter:

```
const user = props => ( // <−−−− Here
  <Aux>
    <UserTable title="User" type="user" role={props.location.roleAction} />
                                              ^−−−−−− no `this` here since it's
                                                      a parameter
  </Aux>
);
```

This is covered in the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). Here's a simple runnable example:

```js
const Example = props => (
  <div>{props.text}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Example text="one" />
    <Example text="two" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```